# Read and edit .cdb files (Pocket Access) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, cdb

I need to make a program that can read and edit certain .cdb files (Microsoft Pocket Accesss files, created and used by legacy accounting mobile application).

I'd like to do that in C#, using VS2008. It would be great to be able to create both a desktop application (.Net) and a mobile application (.Net CF), but just one of them is perfectly fine.

What libraries, configuration, etc... do you recommend me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pocket Access was deprecated long ago and no automation model for the files ended up making it into the Compact Framework.  In The Hand used to offer an "ADOCE" .NET wrapper - I found eval versions of it with my search engine, but I can't find it [on their actual web site](http://inthehand.com/), making me think it's discontinued and likely no longer available for purchase.

I don't think the necessary ADOCE infrastructure even exists on newer (WinMo 5.0 and later devices) so it wouldn't work at all there anyway.

If it's at all possible, I'd try to modify the legacy app (eVB?) to have a text export that you could then use.